# KeyError when using a different csv file as input

Tags: python, csv

I have this code which basically for a csv input file, prints out the minimum cost and restaurant id for the item/items. But its throwing "KeyError" on one input file, but works flawlessly on another (both of same style). Could anybody point out where is it wrong ? Thanks

Some important considerations::
CHALLENGES ::

1. My customer doesnt want to visit multiple restaurants. So for example if he asks for "extreme_fajita,jalapeno_poppers,extra_salsa" then the code should print shop 6 (where it is available as a combo item), instead of scattering the user requirement around different restaurants (even if some restaurant is offering it cheap).
2. Secondly & most importantly: Suppose the user asks for burger.Then if a certain restaurant 'X' is giving a "burger" for 4$, whereas another restaurant 'Y' is giving "burger+tuna+tofu" for $3, then we will tell the user to got for RESTAURANT 'Y', even if it has extra items apart from the 'burger' which user asked for, but we are happy to give them extra items as long as its cheap.

---

```
def build_shops(shop_text):
    shops = {}
    for item_info in shop_text:
        shop_id,cost,items = item_info.replace('\n', '').split(',')
        cost = float(cost)
        items = items.split('+')

        if shop_id not in shops:
            shops[shop_id] = {}
        shop_dict = shops[shop_id]

        for item in items:
            if item not in shop_dict:
                shop_dict[item] = []
            shop_dict[item].append([cost,items])
    return shops


def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    all_possible = []
    first_item = items[0]
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
        sub_set = [x for x in items if x not in combo]
        price_sub_set,solution = solve_one_shop(shop, sub_set)
        solution.append([price,combo])
        all_possible.append([price+price_sub_set, solution])

    cheapest = min(all_possible, key=(lambda x: x[0]))
    return cheapest


def solver(input_data, required_items):
    shops = build_shops(input_data)
    print shops
    result_all_shops = []
    for shop_id,shop_info in shops.iteritems():
        (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
        result_all_shops.append([shop_id, price, solution])

    shop_id,total_price,solution = min(result_all_shops, key=(lambda x: x[1]))
    print('SHOP_ID=%s' % shop_id)
    sln_str = [','.join(items)+'(%0.2f)'%price for (price,items) in solution]
    sln_str = '+'.join(sln_str)
    print(sln_str + ' = %0.2f' % total_price)



shop_text = open('input.csv','rb')    
#shops = build_shops(shop_text)
#cheapest=solve_one_shop(shops,items)
solver(shop_text,['A'])
```

**input.csv**

```
1,4.00,tuna
1,8.00,tofu
2,5.00,tuna
2,6.50,tofu
3,4.00,chef_salad
3,8.00,steak__sandwich
4,5.00,steak__sandwich
4,2.50,wine_spritzer
5,4.00,extreme_fajita
5,8.00,fancy_eu_water
6,5.00,fancy_eu_water
6,6.00,extreme_fajita+jalapeno_poppers+extra_salsa
```

But I get this error : -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "working.py", line 56, in <module>
    solver(shop_text,['extra_salsa'])
  File "working.py", line 42, in solver
    (price, solution) = solve_one_shop(shop_info, required_items)
  File "working.py", line 27, in solve_one_shop
    for (price,combo) in shop[first_item]:
KeyError: 'extra_salsa'
```

Whereas if I run it on another input file , I get correct answer and dont get any error.

**input.csv**

```
1,2.00,A
1,1.25,B
1,2.00,C
1,1.00,D
1,1.00,A+B
1,1.50,A+C
1,2.50,A+D
2,3.00,A
2,1.00,B
2,1.20,C
2,1.25,D
```

**========OUTPUT=========**

```
{'1': {'A': [[2.0, ['A']], [1.0, ['A', 'B']], [1.5, ['A', 'C']], [2.5, ['A', 'D']]], 'C': [[2.0, ['C']], [1.5, ['A', 'C']]], 'B': [[1.25, ['B']], [1.0, ['A', 'B']]], 'D': [[1.0, ['D']], [2.5, ['A', 'D']]]}, '2': {'A': [[3.0, ['A']]], 'C': [[1.2, ['C']]], 'B': [[1.0, ['B']]], 'D': [[1.25, ['D']]]}}

SHOP_ID=1
A,B(1.00) = 1.00
```

Answer (score 2):

> What happens where is no `extra_salsa` in your shop?

Other than angry salsa loving customers, your script doesn't work because the key doesn't exist.

Just like you are checking if `items` is empty, you need to check if the item requested is actually in the shop or not:

```
def solve_one_shop(shop, items):
    if len(items) == 0:
        return [0.0, []]
    all_possible = []
    # first_item = items[0]
    for item in items:
        price,combo = shop.get(item, (0.0,[])) # This will return 
                                               # default values when
                                               # the key doesn't exist
```

---

Lets start by optimizing your load code:

```
import csv

from collections import defaultdict

def build_shops(shop_file_name):
    shops = defaultdict(list)
    with open(shop_file_name, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            id, cost, items = row
            cost = float(cost)
            items = items.split('+')
            shops[id].append((cost, items,))
    return shops
```

Now we have one function that returns dictionary, each key is a list of tuples representing the cost and a list of items.

Next, lets optimize the solver:

```
def solver(shops, required_items):
    result_all_shops = []
    shops_with_items = []

    for i in required_items:
        for shop, inventory in shops.iteritems():
            for price, items in inventory:
                if i in items:
                    shops_with_items.append((shop, price, i))

    if not shops_with_items:
        return []  # No shops contained the items

    for i in required_items:
        result_all_shops.append(min(filter(lambda x: x[2] == i, shops_with_items),
                                               key=lambda x: x[1]))

    return result_all_shops
```

Finally, to load everything up:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    shops = build_shops('input.csv')
    items = ['extra_salsa','tofu']
    result = solver(shops, items)
    if not result:
       print('Sorry, no shops contained {}'.format(','.join(items)))
    else:
       for shop, item, price in result:
           print('Shop {} had the item {} for {}'.format(shop,price,item)))
```

Comment: Thanks burhan. But extra_salsa is there at restaurant-6 . Secondly I get the same error if I query for solver(shop_text,['tuna']) . Thirdly if I replace the items with alphabets only (i.e. 'A' for 'tuna', 'B' for 'tofu', etc.), and if I do solver(shop_text,['A']), I get exactly the correct result as required. Why this different behaviour on two csv files ??

Comment: Burhan Ive edited my post to include correct output also, and the file on which my code is working. please have a look and help me fix it. Thanks !!!!

Comment: Burkhan but if the customer wants : -'extreme_fajita,jalapeno_poppers,extra_salsa' then your code is giving 2 seperate restaurants 5,6. But the customer wants to have his requested meal at a single restaurant only (if all available), which in this case is restaurant 6. PLEASE SEE -- IVE EDITED MY POST & ADDED "IMPORTANT CONSIDERATIONS"

Comment: You need to be able to edit this yourself from now on :)